# Spring Boot war favicon not showing/resolved

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, favicon

I have the problem that my favicon is not showing up if I have deployed the war file. In my IDE its working.

I am using Spring Boot and packacking war. The favicon.ico is stored in the folder src/main/resources and also in src/main/resources/static like in the most pages described.
In the packaged war file I also see the favicon.ico. I have linked it also on the jsp page.

Icon is not showing up. I think the problem is that the tomcat is looking in a different folder. Interesting would also why if I start from the IDE its working and if I start the war its not.

**Clipping from jsp file**

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

**Location of "favicon.ico"**, stored this icon in "src/main/resources" and also in the subfolder static.

[image: location favicon.ico]

Comment: Could you share you code please? How do you try to access to your file?

Comment: Added where I have stored the favicon.ico and also how I reference on that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. My solution was to create a @Requestmapping for favicon.ico to present it from the webserver.

```
    @RequestMapping("favicon.ico")
        String favicon() {
        return "forward:/myfavicon.ico";
    }
```

Config application.properties

```
spring.mvc.favicon.enabled=false
```

And of course placed the icon in the root directory of my application in the IDE.